# Android download multiple files with OkHttp and coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

In my app, I get a set of urls to some images from an api and need to create `Bitmap` objects out of those urls to be able do display the images in the UI. I saw that the android docs recommend using corutines for performing such async tasks, but I am not sure how to do it properly.

Using OkHttp for my http client, I tried the following approach:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
                    val gson = Gson();
                    val parsedRes = gson.fromJson(
                        response.body?.charStream(),
                        Array<GoodreadsBook>::class.java
                    );
                    // Create the bitmap from the imageUrl
                    for (i in 0 until parsedRes.size) {
                        val bitmap =
                            GlobalScope.async { createBitmapFromUrl(parsedRes[i].best_book.image_url) }
                        parsedRes[i].best_book.imageBitmap = bitmap.await();
                    }
                   searchResults.postValue(parsedRes)
                }
```

Where `response` is what I get back from my API, and `searchResults` is a `LiveData` that hold the parsed response.
Also, here is how I am getting the images from those urls:

```
suspend fun createBitmapFromUrl(url: String): Bitmap? {
    val client = OkHttpClient();
    val req = Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    val res = client.newCall(req).execute();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res.body?.byteStream())
}
```

Even though every fetch action is done on a separate coroutine, it's still too slow. Is there a better way of doing it? I can use any other http client if there is one out there optimized for use with coroutines, although I am new to Kotlin so I don't know any.

Comment: First you should determine the cause of the slowness, which might well be outside this piece of code. Is it the server? Your internet connection?

Comment: check this https://github.com/square/okio

Comment: `bitmap.await()` You've await inside the loop, that would suspend the loop until that deferred is completed.

Comment: Consider using Picasso or Glide or Coil, they will download and cache the images for you.

Comment: @Thomas, I am running my app in the emulator, so there might  be some network slowdown due to that. Running the profiler shows that in fact the network requests take a bit on their own, but my implementation ran slower the the one presented by Animesh Sahu

Comment: @Fabio, any performance difference between these?

Comment: They're roughly the same, but certainly offer many more features than you or me are capable of doing by ourselves in any reasonable amount of time.  https://link.medium.com/Fv1goh6lV7

Comment: I see that these libraries load the image directly into my View. Is there a way to use any of these libraries with data binding? I added data binding for the rest of my UI and mixing these to approaches of binding data to views is quite messy

Comment: Never mind, I went again though the data binding docs and I found how to do it. This might be the best approach so thanks!

Comment: Tried using Picasso. I guess the caching helps, but other than that the performance is quite the same. Although easier to implement than using OKHttp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the `createBitmapFromUrl(url: String)` does everything synchronously, you've to first stop them from blocking the coroutine thread, you may want to use `Dispatchers.IO` for that because callback isn't the most idomatic thing ever in coroutines.

```kotlin
val client = OkHttpClient()  // preinitialize the client

suspend fun createBitmapFromUrl(url: String): Bitmap? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val req = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val res = client.newCall(req).execute()
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res.body?.byteStream())
}
```

Now, when you are calling `bitmap.await()` you are simply saying that "Hey, wait for the deferred `bitmap` and once it is finished resume the loop for next iteration"

So you may want to do the assignment in the coroutine itself to stop it from suspending the loop, otherwise create another loop for that. I'd go for first option.

```kotlin
scope.launch {
    val gson = Gson();
    val parsedRes = gson.fromJson(
        response.body?.charStream(),
        Array<GoodreadsBook>::class.java
    );
    // Create the bitmap from the imageUrl
    for (i in 0 until parsedRes.size) {
        launch {
            parsedRes[i].best_book.imageBitmap = createBitmapFromUrl(parsedRes[i].best_book.image_url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't return a value from the `withContext` block

Comment: @AdrianPascu ah sorry, just remove the `return` keyword, the last statement in lambda is automatically returned :) Fixed it. Otherwise you can use qualified return like `return@withContext <return value>`

Comment: Oh yeah, that is a lambda. Still not used to this block syntax. I'll try it out

Comment: I had to edit my post, so if you may look over it again it would be great. With my approach this wasn't relevant, but after the for loop, after updating each element, I modify a LiveData object that holds the entire array. With the approach you are now suggesting, updating the LiveData isn't possible since the changes in the array won't reflect right away. Is there a way to also implement this? Other languages let you chain async tasks, but I can't find anything similar in Kotlin.

Comment: @AdrianPascu the outer coroutine launched in the scope will return a job which waits until all its children to finish. You can create another coroutine then do `job.join()` (suspending call) that will resume when all the values are set in the array. Then you can update your livedata.

Comment: Yeah, this works.Thanks! The network requests still take a bit though, although I guess this is limited by the server that hosts those images. Could running the fetching job from a background service compensate a bit for the network slowdown?

Comment: @AdrianPascu dispatching to `Dispatchers.IO` indeed is backed by a max of 64 threads, I think this is the max we could optimize, other thing you could do is that use a MutableStateFlow instead of LiveData, and send the updates as soon as the image is downloaded with specific index (instead of letting all of them (images) to complete and then notifying the livedata).

Comment: This way you can start updating UI, as soon as the request are getting complete. (update those UI whose indexes are completed loading the images, and put others with a loading gif)

Comment: I'll have to try that. So many kotlin features I don't know of... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like the following that doesn't use the blocking `execute` method and instead bridges from the async `enqueue`.

https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp

```
suspend fun main() {
    // Do call and await() for result from any suspend function
    val result = client.newCall(request).await()
    println("${result.code()}: ${result.message()}")
}
```

What this basically does is the following

```
public suspend fun Call.await(): Response {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                continuation.resume(response)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                if (continuation.isCancelled) return
                continuation.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        })

        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
            try {
                cancel()
            } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                //Ignore cancel exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bit faster looking at the profiler, but the difference is not noticeable

Comment: Sure. But it's more efficient with threads. Nothing wrong with the execute solution.